# Hiding Opened Excel File

Tags: c#, excel, com

here is my question:

I have developed a program that uses Microsoft.Excel COM components in order to read/write over Excel files. Well, my app is doing good but when I open, for instance, another file directly with Excel while my program is running, the file(s) that my app uses appear within Excel. I do not want this. I tried also the Visibility property of Excel Application class, but that was not the solution, it just does not work.

NOTE : I have checked this question out.

[Restrict access to excel file opened by C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349684/restrict-access-to-excel-file-opened-by-c-program)

Yet, it says no proper solution actually.

Comment: Alternatively, consider looking at something like NPOI so you don't need to use Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = true`. This will avoid users opening excel files in the same `Excel` process as the one you are using.

There is one caveat though: you have to make sure that all execution paths of your application reset this property to `false`. This property **WILL NOT** reset itself when you quit and release your `Excel` application which means that `Excel` will not respond correctly to a subsequent user who double clicks on a *.xls file for example.

**EDIT: Possible issues with IgnoreRemoteRequest**

Ok, to make this clearer I'll detail a little bit more what issues you can run into using this feature (at least these are the only ones I've run into when I had to use this feature).

When setting `IgnoreRemoteRequests = true` you have to make sure you reset this property BEFORE quiting and/or releasing the COM Excel application. If you don't, Excel will not respond to DDE requests which means if someone double clicks on a *.xls file, the file will not open (Excel will start up, but it wont open the file automatically).

This however is only true if you quit the application and/or release it without reseting the property. You just have to make sure that wherever it is in your code that you are quitting/resetting you set the `IgnoreRemoteRquests` back to `false` before.

If you'r application crashes and it hasn't been able to clean up (unhandled exception) then the EXCEL process will keep running (if invisible, you will only see it in the Task Manager). That is normal as your app didnt have a chance to quit and release the internal Excel it is using. This however is not an issue. If a user ignores this "leaked" Excel process until it's eventually killed in next reboot or whatever, or manually kills it from the task bar, Excel will work perfectly fine.

Note: MS Excel 2007. Don't know about behavior of previous versions.

Comment: Wait so if you write a program that sets Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = true, you can permanently disable excel opening documents in the same window? That's a "feature" I pretty much NEVER want.

Comment: Read what the poster is asking for. If you set IgnoreRemoteRequests = true, a user who opens a excel file will open the file in a new excel process diferent from the one that the application is internally using which will remain hidden if it was initially. This can be interesting if you do not want the user messing around with the workbook the application is using internally. The problem arises when you exit the internal excel process. If you do not reset the property then you can have an issue.

Comment: I'm saying it annoys the hell out of me that they open in the same window and I'm asking if doing this once in a program just changes excel permanently

Comment: Sorry, connection down. Edits to my answer are up if interested.

Comment: Ah with your longer explanation that would result in an unexpected/undesired behavior if you didn't clean that up.

Comment: @InBetween I really thank you about this and longer explanation. I just added a few code lines and it just worked. This is the exact answer to this problem. I hope it will be helpful for other users too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your program under a service account? This should avoid the excel com object interfering with the instance used by the logged in console user, so they will not see the effects of your com objects. It's probably also better security practice to run COM type applications under a service account instead of a user account as well, but that's for another question.