# Keep my instance of Excel Interop process independent of desktop session

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have recently been working with Excel Interop is C# and I have come across an interesting problem.

When my console Excel Interop application is running, it has an Excel process running. While it is running, if I click on an excel file in, say, Windows Explorer, it opens up the clicked file in the same instance of my interop process.

I can sort of understand this: if I had a regular session of Excel open and I click on a new file, it will open that file in the same instance.

Of course I don’t want this to happen with my Interop application, I want it to run independent of anything the user does externally. How can I stop it?

(Sorry if the title is misleading, I wasn’t sure how to describe it… or Google it!)

**Clarification based on comments below from (ADyson & gravity):**

The scenario is a user double-clicks on an Excel file, rather than starting the application directly, at the same time as Interop is instantiating Excel. So the double-clicked file opens up in the Interop Excel instance.

Comment: I think I understand the gist of what you're asking for here.. but I'm a bit confused as to this portion: "_my console Excel Interop application is running (**batch-style**)_".  What do you mean by **batch-style**?  Also, have you looked into something such as EPPlus?  They don't have to instantiate Excel instances at all.

Comment: @Gravity I've edited that line, it was confusing. I am aware of EEPlus and I would prefer to use it but it isn't an option right now at my work.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. You've opened Excel as if you were the user...the context is entirely the same, only the method of opening the application is slightly different. If you then try to open another Excel file, the O/S will see that the Excel process is already running and use it to open the file. I suspect if you wanted to change this you'd have to change how Windows itself works.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of suggesting is whether you can run your console program as another user (I mean using a runas context for it), maybe that would start Excel as the other user, and perhaps it would then be considered separate when trying to open another file. I don't know if it would even work but it's worth a try. Beyond that your only other option is really to move your processing to another machine entirely.

Comment: @ADyson So, this is a bit tricky, but it falls back on using the `Visible` feature, so that the end-user falls into two categories:  1.  They don't realize Excel is using Interop in the background (so they open Excel, and it instantiates a separate copy), or 2.  Already have Excel open (so `new Application` instantiates the new copy).  It's not cut and dry, nor foolproof, but it does work separately if you do it correctly.

Comment: @Gravity Yes, you’ve clarified the user issue: they *don’t* know or care that the application is using Excel, so as per usual; they click on an Excel file, expecting it to open up a fresh instance and load the file. They don’t know that it will use the already running process. If they *do* open the Excel program explicitly and then access their file from there, everything is fine of course. But I don’t want them to worry about it.

Comment: @gravity agreed, but I'm not sure you've accounted for the case where a user double-clicks on an Excel file, rather than starting the application directly. This scenario appears to be the problem at stake. Will making it invisible deal with that?

Comment: @ADyson Exactly.

Comment: @ADyson That's exactly right.  So, to that specific point (double-clicking a file while Interop is instantiating Excel) that will always be a problem.  Hence the recommendation for something like EPPlus.

Comment: @Adyson and gravity: I rather thought that would be the case (that there is no solution) but had my hopes up. EPPlus sounds very promising from what I have heard; I’ll have to push for it. Thanks.

Comment: there are other libraries as well which can work with Excel files, but EPPPlus is a reasonable choice yes, you should do a bit of research into the possibilities if you can. As well as solving this problem, operating directly on the files themselves instead of manipulating the application GUI will make your code both faster (no intermediary application execution required) and less prone to randomly crashing (in my experience interop does this surprisingly often) - so these are arguments you can push as well when you make your case for a change.

Comment: Are you starting Excel in your command line? Or are you using the Interop object model?

Comment: @JuanR My application has an Interop instance of Excel and the user is trying to open an Excel file independently by double-clicking. See clarification and the comments from ADyson & gravity.

Comment: I did read the comments. The reason I decided to ask again is that I just ran a quick test and I see Excel opening new instances without reusing the Interop one. Please post sample code to see how you are interacting via Interop.

Comment: I'm 85% sure you'll want to set the Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests property to true to prevent this from happening.

Comment: @Hans Passant That seems to work like a charm! (This is likely what JuanR would have pointed out.) Please post as answer. And Thanks!

Comment: You don't really need me to finish the Q+A you started, simply create your own post and share what you learned.  And mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I spoke too soon. I am seeing a strange side effect: If I run my console app with “myExcelApp.Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = true”, when it completes I can’t open *any* Excel file by double-clicking. I get a pop-up error “There was a problem sending the command to the program.” Then I have to run my application again with that property set to "false" to resolve.

Comment: You probably are not disposing of the `Application` properly.  Do you have a `Application.Quit` provided, along with garbage collection/disposal as well?

Comment: @gravity: Yes to both. That isn't the problem.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input: I should have posted earlier that, per Hans suggestion, I have revamped my code to set 'myExcelApp.Application.IgnoreRemoteRequests = true' and reset it to false before exit. I've recently found a good explanation here [Hiding Opened Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278915/hiding-opened-excel-file). It stresses that you must be sure to reset to false even if your excel interop process fails otherwise you wont be able to open a file by clicking.